# Express preference in case of ambiguous templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword, specialization

Given the following code:

```
struct Zero{};

template<typename T>
Zero operator*(const Zero& zero, const T& other){return Zero();}

struct Identity{};

template<typename T>
T operator*(const T& other, const Identity& id){return T();}
```

Now, I want to use this code like this:

```
Zero z;
Identity id;
int i = 5;
z * i; // ok
i * id; // ok
z * id; //error: ambiguity in function resolution
```

The compiler will not be able to resolve the operator in the last line, because both functions could be used. In fact in this case I do not care which function is used, since they have the same functionality. In both cases Zero() will be returned as expected.

My Question: How can I express that in this case any of the functions are ok to use?

Comment: BTW: You might want to take a look at `constexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one more overload (which is not a template whatsoever):

```
Zero operator*(const Zero& other, const Identity& id){return Zero();}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use SFINAE to remove the first template from consideration if `T` is `Identity`:

```
template<typename T> auto operator*(const Zero& zero, const T& other)
-> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, Identity>::value, Zero>::value
{return {};}
```

Comment: I like this answer. Although, it makes the code more convoluted, it is preferable when I start having different versions of the operator* (e.g. when 'Identity' or 'Zero' are templated). In the previous answer I would have to duplicate code. Thanks a lot!